# In the movie Constantine, what was the significance of the glass jars hanging from the ceiling in Beeman's room?

Tags: dc, constantine-2005, constantine

There were a lot of glass jars hanging from the ceiling in Beeman's room in the bowling alley. What does this mean? Obviously, Google brings up glass bottles in trees and catching spirits, etc. Is there more? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by adding a screenshot of the room with the jars for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Lots of people store things on the ceiling. It's a good way of using an otherwise useless space; https://preview.redd.it/9flqu56g6me51.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=8759923970818ff88c7716e8ed59cb5df1cc8811

Comment: Another view of the jars; https://i0.wp.com/superherocinephiles.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/constantine.jpg?fit=1200%2C675&ssl=1

Answer (score 2):

Beeman is a collector of exotic materials and insects, i can't say with a 100% certainty but by the looks of the jars in the movie and his interest in insects it looks like he is using them to store those insects.